# Find entity by unique field with QueryDSL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, querydsl

Supposing that I'm working on `MyEntity` table within the `name` field have to be unique (but not primary key).

I'd like to define a `findByName` method by using **QueryDSL**.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
public MyEntity findByName(final String name) {
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(this.entityManager);
    QMyEntity myEntity;
    List<MyEntity> result = jpaQuery.from(myEntity).where(myEntity.name.eq(name)).list(myEntity);
    if (result.isEmpty())
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    else if (result.size() == 1)
        return result.get(0);
    else
        throw new PersistenceException();
}
```

Is mine a proper solution in order to achieve this task or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [uniqueResult](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.5.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/jpa/impl/AbstractJPAQuery.html#uniqueResult(com.mysema.query.types.Expression)) instead `list`:

```
public MyEntity findByName(final String name) {
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(this.entityManager);
    QMyEntity myEntity;
    MyEntity result = jpaQuery.from(myEntity).where(myEntity.name.eq(name)).uniqueResult(myEntity);
    if (result ==  null)
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    else
        return result;
}
```